# Calculate monthly and weekly occupancy by day in percent

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to python and I have a table of occupancy that looks like this:

```
| room | free| date | place
| room_1 | 0 | 2021-01-13| Boston|    
|room_2 |1| 2021-02-14| Boston|    
|room_2|0|2021-02-15|Boston|
```

...

How can I calculate how often a room was free within a timeframe of a month and a week for each room?

So I could say: room_1 was free for 95 % free within February?
1 = free
0 = not free

I have the data in `csv` format.

Comment: Noel, we need more details about your question. Please specify how you have the data saved. Is it an array, a pandas dataframe? Also, please, post your code and the attempts you have made to achieve what you need.

Comment: Do you mean calendar yearly "week" or calendar monthly "week"?

Comment: once for each month and once for each monthly week.

Comment: so for `2021-01-13`, would that be in week `2` or week `3` counting from `1`?  E.g. `2021-01-01` is a `Friday` so does week 1 consist of `Friday, Saturday` (assuming Sunday is first day of week)?  Or is week 1 all the days `2021-01-01` through `2021-01-06`?

Comment: When you say *"I have a table"* and *"I have the data in CSV format"* , if you mean you have a pandas dataframe read in with `pd.read_csv()`, then please say that (otherwise, what sort of table is it? what type of object?). Also, please tag pandas questions [tag:pandas], then they get answered faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide that can help you.
First i created a dataframe of example and i fixed the 'date' column to a datetime class

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataframe_example=[['room_1',0,'2021-01-13','Boston'],
... ['room_2',1,'2021-02-14','Boston'],
... ['room_2',0,'2021-02-15','Boston'],
... ['room_1',1,'2021-02-17','Boston'],
... ['room_3',1,'2021-01-17','Texas'],
... ['room_2',1,'2021-01-17','Boston'],
... ['room_3',0,'2021-02-18','Texas'],
... ['room_1',0,'2021-02-18','Boston'],
... ['room_2',0,'2021-01-19','Boston'],
... ['room_3',1,'2021-01-19','Texas'],
... ['room_3',0,'2021-01-20','Texas']]
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(dataframe_example,columns=['room','free','date','place'])
>>> df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
>>> df
      room  free       date   place
0   room_1     0 2021-01-13  Boston
1   room_2     1 2021-02-14  Boston
2   room_2     0 2021-02-15  Boston
3   room_1     1 2021-02-17  Boston
4   room_3     1 2021-01-17   Texas
5   room_2     1 2021-01-17  Boston
6   room_3     0 2021-02-18   Texas
7   room_1     0 2021-02-18  Boston
8   room_2     0 2021-01-19  Boston
9   room_3     1 2021-01-19   Texas
10  room_3     0 2021-01-20   Texas
```

Now you create a mask with a start_date and end_date class type datetime ( this is the code you have to edit to your exercise )

```
>>> start_date= pd.to_datetime('2021-01-13',format='%Y-%m-%d')
>>> end_date=pd.to_datetime('2021-01-20',format='%Y-%m-%d')
>>> mask=(df['date']>start_date) & (df['date']<=end_date)
```

create a dataframe mask

```
>>> df_mask=df[mask]
>>>df_mask
      room  free       date   place
4   room_3     1 2021-01-17   Texas
5   room_2     1 2021-01-17  Boston
8   room_2     0 2021-01-19  Boston
9   room_3     1 2021-01-19   Texas
10  room_3     0 2021-01-20   Texas
```

use the loc dataframe to get the room that you want, in my case i want to find the room 3

```
>>> df_mask=df_mask.loc[df_mask['room']=='room_3']
>>> df_mask
      room  free       date  place
4   room_3     1 2021-01-17  Texas
9   room_3     1 2021-01-19  Texas
10  room_3     0 2021-01-20  Texas
```

Now a simple frequency of the free column and divided to the count multipled by 100 to get the porcentage

```
>>> df_mask['free'].value_counts()/df_mask['free'].count()*100
1    66.666667
0    33.333333
```

All done.

I hope you understand everything!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function below, taking as arguments the **dataframe** that you have, and creating a new one with grouped columns, which lets you read the percentage of availability for each of the room, per each month.

Start by importing your csv as a dataframe in pandas, with:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

dataframe = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

Then, you could use the below function to create a new dataframe grouped by rooms, which shows every room, for every particular month and the related availability in percentage.

```
from calendar import monthrange

def getFreePct(df):
    def rowPercentage(row):
        free = row['free']
        year = row['date'].year
        month = row['date'].month
        days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
        return free/days*100

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df = df.groupby(['room', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])['free'].sum().reset_index()
    df['freq'] = df.apply(rowPercentage, axis=1)
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
    df = df.groupby(['room', 'date']).sum()
    return df

df = getFreePct(df)
print(df)
```

The output will be in the following format (these are dummy values):

```
                free      freq
room   date                   
room_1 01/2021     4  45.34442
       02/2021     5  34.34443
room_2 01/2021     6  75.33444
       02/2021     7  63.33333
```

Your `freq` being the frequency of availability, as a percentage.

`free` corresponds to how many times during that month the room was free

`date` is the month

`room`, well, is the room

If you would like to have a playable example, you could run:

```
import pandas as pd
from calendar import monthrange

dataframe_example=[['room_1',0,'2021-01-13','Boston'],
['room_1',1,'2021-01-01','Boston'],
['room_2',0,'2021-02-02','Boston'],
['room_2',0,'2021-03-03','Boston'],
['room_1',1,'2021-01-04','Boston'],
['room_2',1,'2021-02-05','Boston'],
['room_2',0,'2021-03-06','Boston'],
['room_1',0,'2021-01-07','Boston'],
['room_2',0,'2021-02-08','Boston'],
['room_2',1,'2021-02-09','Boston'],
['room_1',1,'2021-03-10','Boston']]

df=pd.DataFrame(dataframe_example,columns=['room','free','date','place'])

def getFreePct(df):
    def rowPercentage(row):
        free = row['free']
        year = row['date'].year
        month = row['date'].month
        days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
        return free/days*100

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df = df.groupby(['room', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])['free'].sum().reset_index()
    df['freq'] = df.apply(rowPercentage, axis=1)
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
    df = df.groupby(['room', 'date']).sum()
    return df

df = getFreePct(df)
print(df)
```

To get your **week** data, adjust the function as follows:

```
def getFreePct(df):
    def rowPercentage(row):
        free = row['free']
        return free/7*100

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df = df.groupby(['room', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W')])['free'].sum().reset_index()
    df['freq'] = df.apply(rowPercentage, axis=1)
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    df = df.groupby(['room', 'date']).sum()
    return df

df = getFreePct(df)
print(df)
```

And expect the following output format:

```
                   free       freq
room   date                       
room_1 2021/01/03     1  14.285714
       2021/01/10     1  14.285714
       2021/01/17     2  28.571429
       2021/02/07     1  14.285714
       2021/03/14     2  28.571429
room_2 2021/01/10     1  14.285714
       2021/01/17     1  14.285714
       2021/02/07     1  14.285714
       2021/03/14     1  14.285714
```

If you, instead, only need to extract the data on a per-need basis, you could try running this function, which will take as inputs your **dataframe**, the **room**(*string*), the **year**(*int*) and the **month**(*int*)

```
def getFreePercentage(d, room, year, month):
    d['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d['date'])
    dateStr = str(year) + '-' + str(month)
    d = d[((d.date.dt.month == month) & (d.date.dt.year == year))]
    d = d.loc[d['room' ]== room]
    freeTime = d['free'].sum()
    freeEntries = d['free'].count()
    freq = freeTime/freeEntries*100
    return freq
```

So that

`percentage = getFreePercentage(dataframe, 'room_2', 2021, 2)`

`print(percentage)`

Will output:

`50.0`

Comment: Jan 2021, 4 days free out of 31 days is not 45 percent.

Comment: Have you read `these are dummy values`, it was just to display the format

Comment: I don’t see any ```week``` data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @Marichyasana. I had forgotten the `week` data. I have edited my answer to take account of those. Thanks.